# strpos() not working with french accent

Tags: php, strpos

Hello I have a string with these words : --

```
 $cat = 'vêtement bébé garçon'
```

I am trying to find if the word `bébé` exist in the string. I am using

```
strpos($cat, 'bébé') !== FALSE;
```

but it always return false. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try with **m**ulti **b**yte_strpos -> [`mb_strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) does that do the trick for you?

Comment: still returning false

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe use `$cat` as haystack ?!

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://3v4l.org/EFJLQ) The only explanation would be that your strings are not in fact identical. For that you'll have to go into details of where they come from.

Comment: Indeed, the "multibyte-version" *should* work, and no other version should work, because these characters are represented by multiple bytes.  If they are not seeming to be working, then you may assume that there's an insect in your code.

Comment: @Mike Even regular `strpos` will work just fine, since it's just naively comparing raw bytes. The only thing it won't do is give you an accurate position reading, but that seems to be unnecessary in this case anyway.

Comment: My humble opinion is that the code ought to "clearly do what you would ordinarily think it does," and "return what you would ordinarily think it should."  You're looking for "the position of 'a character.'"  And, therefore, that's what you want to get back.  It is necessary to use the mb_ version of the function, in PHP, to do that.  So, that's always what you should do.  (Otherwise, "even if it 'seems to work,' it's broken.")